# Aligning QLabel in center of an GGraphicsEllipseItem in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem

Im am wondering if there is any way to position a Qlabel in the middle of a 'sector' in my pie chart, which I have designed with PyQt. The sectors are QgraphicsEllipseItems that I have assigned with corresponding start- and span angles. So far, I have tried to put the label in a QGraphicsProxyItem and set the 'Slice' or 'Sector' as the parent. Then, I have tried to position the label in the middle of the 'Sector'. However, the problem is that the boundingRect is a rectangle rather than just the 'Sector' itself.

Current Piechart

[image]

In the picture above, you can see the problem. The labels are not positioned correctly. I am trying to achieve something like this with the labels:

Model chart with labels in correct place

[image]

Current code:

```
    pie = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(60, 110, self.piechart.width, self.piechart.height)
    pie.setTransformOriginPoint(pie.boundingRect().center())
    pie.setZValue(-1)
    self.scene.addItem(pie)

    start_angle = 0


    for sector in self.piechart.sectors:
        slice = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(60, 110, self.piechart.width, self.piechart.height, parent=pie)
        color = QtGui.QBrush(sector.color)
        slice.setBrush(color)
        span_angle = sector.proportional_volume*360*16
        slice.setStartAngle(start_angle)
        slice.setSpanAngle(span_angle)
        start_angle += span_angle

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(str(round(sector.proportional_volume*100,2))+'%', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        label.setStyleSheet('background-color: transparent')
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times', 8)
        font.setBold(True)
        label.setFont(font)

        proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget(slice)
        proxy.setWidget(label)
        proxy.setPos(slice.boundingRect().center()) 

        self.scene.addItem(slice)
        self.scene.addItem(proxy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the center of the bounding rect because of geometrical reasons (from the basic [QGraphicsItem.boundingRect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) definition):

> This pure virtual function defines the outer bounds of the item as a rectangle

This means that no matter the shape of the item is, the bounding rect is a rectangle that includes the *whole* shape of the item.
In the following image you can clearly see that "*this isn't the center you're looking for*" [cit.]:

[image: bounding rect center not in the middle]

What you actually need is the center in the *middle axis* of each slice, so it's just a matter of dividing in half the extent of that slice and use half of the radius.

Note that graphics items (just like widgets) normally use their top left corner as a reference for their positions, and if you use the "middle" for that, you won't get a correct result:

[image: label not centered]

To avoid this, you have to subtract the center of the label rectangle, so that it will be correctly centered where you want it.

```
        # create a common rectangle, since we're going to use the same coordinates
        # for all ellipses
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(60, 110, self.piechart.width, self.piechart.height)
        pie = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect)
        pie.setTransformOriginPoint(pie.boundingRect().center())
        pie.setZValue(-1)
        self.scene.addItem(pie)

        # the center position is half of the radius, or a quarter of the size
        labelRadius = self.piechart.width * .25
        center = rect.center()
        start_angle = 0


        for sector in self.piechart.sectors:
            slice = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect, parent=pie)
            slice.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
            color = QtGui.QBrush(sector.color)
            slice.setBrush(color)
            span_angle = sector.proportional_volume*360*16
            slice.setStartAngle(start_angle)
            slice.setSpanAngle(span_angle)
            # we need the current start_angle later, let's do this later
            # start_angle += span_angle

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(str(round(sector.proportional_volume*100,2))+'%', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
            label.setStyleSheet('background-color: transparent')
            font = QtGui.QFont('Times', 8)
            font.setBold(True)
            label.setFont(font)

            proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget(slice)
            proxy.setWidget(label)

            # get the middle angle of the slice
            angle = start_angle / 16 + sector.proportional_volume * 180

            # create a line that has a length that's a quarter of the radius, and
            # has an angle that is in the middle of the current slice; finally,
            # get its end point (p2)
            line = QtCore.QLineF.fromPolar(labelRadius, angle)
            middlePoint = line.p2()

            # the above can also be achieved by using trigonometry functions; note
            # that the sine is negative, since QGraphicsScene coordinates are
            # inverted vertically (downwards coordinates are positive)
            # x = cos(radians(angle)) * labelRadius
            # y = -sin(radians(angle)) * labelRadius
            # middlePoint = QtCore.QPointF(x, y)

            # finally, translate the point to the center of the ellipse
            middlePoint += center
            r = QtCore.QRectF(-1, -1, 2, 2)
            self.scene.addEllipse(r.translated(middlePoint))

            # center the label at that point by subtracting its own center
            proxy.setPos(middlePoint - label.rect().center())

            start_angle += span_angle

            # when you create a QGraphicsItem with a parent that has already been
            # added to the scene, there's no need to add it again
            # self.scene.addItem(slice)
            # self.scene.addItem(proxy)
```

Consider that from a graphical point of view the actual "middle" position will often be perceived closer to the center, due to an optical illusion based on the geometry of the slice and the visual perception of characters; the following image is based on the code above, and as you can see the small light-green slice on the right (4.76%) seems offset, even if *it is* correctly centered:

[image: final result]

So, you might prefer to use a slightly higher ratio for the `labelRadius` (for example, 0.3).

Finally, two considerations:

- some percentages might be very small, you could end up with some labels being partially hidden by the next slice; you should probably prefer to avoid parenting the label to the slice
- using a QGraphicsProxyWidget for a simple QLabel is unnecessary, consider using [QGraphicsSimpleTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssimpletextitem.html) or [QGraphicsTextItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html), but carefully read their documentation as their coordinate system don't exactly behave in the same way.